# Background color in pgfplots that extends beyond the axis of the plot

Tags: pgfplots, backgrounds

I am interested in adding a background-color to my `pgfplots` plot that extends beyond the axis of the plot. See the image bellow for clarification; I am interested in adding a background color such as the plot in the image.

How would you achieve this?

[image]

*Example from: The pgfplots manual (Christian Feuersänger, 2012, p. 20)*

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This is actually done by TikZ (the PGF manual has the same background in its code examples). Take a look into the `backgrounds` library in the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 14):

As Qrrbrbirlbel suggested, you might use the `backgrounds` library from TikZ. The example I provide you uses as predefined color the same one adopted in the pgfmanual and in the pgfplots documentation, but it can be easily changed via a specific key.

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
% background color definition from pgfmanual-en-macros.tex
\definecolor{graphicbackground}{rgb}{0.96,0.96,0.8}
% key to change color
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  background color/.initial=graphicbackground,
  background color/.get=\backcol,
  background color/.store in=\backcol,
}
\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={
    fill=\backcol,
  },
  use background/.style={    
    show background rectangle
  }
}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use background]
\begin{axis}
\addplot {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[background color=orange!20,use background]
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[only marks] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility would be to create plots and figures in separate files with [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) and include them into main document through `\includegraphics` but with a color box providing a background color.

`standalone` provides options `tikz` and `border`. First one places every `tikzpicture` in a separate page. This way you can have a file with all plots/tikzfigures and select them with `page=...` option in `\includegraphics` command. `border` option enlarges figure with an outside margin of certain length. So, processing next file you will get a pdf file with two pages. Each page will contain one plot enlarged 2mm.

```
% file: 101603b.tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[only marks] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Next file is the main document where graphics are included. Command `\myincludegraphics` adds a `\colorbox` of `backgroundcolor`. You can change it with `\colorlet` or include the background color as a parameter in `\myincludegraphics` definition.

```
%file: 101603.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{253,245,238}

\newcommand{\myincludegraphics}[2][]{%
\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\colorbox{backgroundcolor}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
\endgroup}


\begin{document}

\myincludegraphics[page=1]{101603b}

\colorlet{backgroundcolor}{red!20}
\myincludegraphics[page=2]{101603b}

\end{document}
```

The result is similar to the one shown in [Claudio's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101610/1952).